# Django error: TypeError at /forums/ 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

I am making a Django forums project and I have run into this issue. whenever I go to my forum page I see this error: TypeError at /forums/ 'str' object is not callable. If anyone knows how to fix this I would appreciate the help.

forms:

```
from django import forms
from  . import models

class ForumForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Post
        fields = ('message',)
```

models

```
    from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

URLs

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'forums'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ForumForm.as_view(), name='forum')
]
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic
from . import forms
# Create your views here.

class ForumForm(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'forums_simple/forum.html'
    form_class = 'ForumForm'
    success_url = '/'

    def form_vaild(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_vaild(form)
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `form_class = 'ForumForm'` to `form_class = forms.ForumForm`.